# How do I extract a string?

Tags: string, vbscript

Using VB script, I have this example:

```
myString = "\js\security\security.js"
newString = 'get the string after the last '\' which is the filename.

echo newString
```

How can I extract so that the output will be the string: `security.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filesystem object and do all operations using that. [Documentation GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a99s8akf(v=vs.84).aspx).

```
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
newString = fso.GetFileName(myString)
```